# Exception in thread "main" java.net.SocketException: Unrecognized Windows Sockets error: 0: Cannot bind when using Jgroups

Tags: sockets, tcp, jgroups

I am trying to run the [SimpleChat](http://jgroups.org/tutorial4/code/SimpleChat.java) program from Jgroups tutorial using tcp protocol on three different systems in the same subnet. The program runs fine (joins the groups, sends messages between the nodes) on two of the three systems. When I try to run the same program with the same settings on my third machine I see

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.SocketException: Unrecognized Windows Sockets error: 0: Cannot bind
    at java.net.TwoStacksPlainDatagramSocketImpl.bind0(Native Method)
    at java.net.TwoStacksPlainDatagramSocketImpl.bind0(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainDatagramSocketImpl.bind(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.TwoStacksPlainDatagramSocketImpl.bind(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.DatagramSocket.bind(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.MulticastSocket.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.MulticastSocket.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.jgroups.util.DefaultSocketFactory.createMulticastSocket(DefaultSocketFactory.java:88)
    at org.jgroups.stack.DiagnosticsHandler.start(DiagnosticsHandler.java:91)
    at org.jgroups.protocols.TP.startDiagnostics(TP.java:977)
    at org.jgroups.protocols.TP.start(TP.java:918)
    at org.jgroups.protocols.TCP.start(TCP.java:103)
    at org.jgroups.stack.ProtocolStack.startStack(ProtocolStack.java:861)
    at org.jgroups.JChannel.startStack(JChannel.java:1017)
    at org.jgroups.JChannel._preConnect(JChannel.java:886)
    at org.jgroups.JChannel.connect(JChannel.java:390)
    at org.jgroups.JChannel.connect(JChannel.java:384)
    at com.test.jgroup.demo.SimpleChat.start(SimpleChat.java:78)
    at com.test.jgroup.demo.SimpleChat.main(SimpleChat.java:145)
```

Ignore the line numbers as I added some sysout statements to the program but the core logic is untouched. All my machines are windows 10(64-bit) running java 8. 
This is my tcp.xml on my third machine:

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns="urn:org:jgroups"
        xsi:schemaLocation="urn:org:jgroups http://www.jgroups.org/schema/jgroups.xsd">
    <TCP bind_addr="10.108.80.170"
         bind_port="6500"
         recv_buf_size="${tcp.recv_buf_size:130k}"
         send_buf_size="${tcp.send_buf_size:130k}"
         max_bundle_size="64K"
         sock_conn_timeout="300"

         thread_pool.min_threads="0"
         thread_pool.max_threads="20"
         thread_pool.keep_alive_time="30000"/>

    <TCPPING async_discovery="true"
             initial_hosts="${jgroups.tcpping.initial_hosts:10.108.80.63[7800],10.108.80.116[5600]}"
             max_dynamic_hosts="10"/>
    <MERGE3  min_interval="10000"
             max_interval="30000"/>
    <FD_SOCK/>
    <FD timeout="3000" max_tries="3" />
    <VERIFY_SUSPECT timeout="1500"  />
    <BARRIER />
    <pbcast.NAKACK2 use_mcast_xmit="false"
                   discard_delivered_msgs="true"/>
    <UNICAST3 />
    <pbcast.STABLE desired_avg_gossip="50000"
                   max_bytes="4M"/>
    <pbcast.GMS print_local_addr="true" join_timeout="2000"/>
    <MFC max_credits="2M"
         min_threshold="0.4"/>
    <FRAG2 frag_size="60K"  />
    <!--RSVP resend_interval="2000" timeout="10000"/-->
    <pbcast.STATE_TRANSFER/>
</config>
```

I tried running the program by setting -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true but see
 `Exception in thread "main" java.net.BindException: Address already in use: Cannot bind`

Comment: Is some other process using port 6500? `netstat -an |grep 6500` will show. And is the bind address of `10.108.80.170` correct?

Comment: No other process is using port 6500. I tried using different ports as well.  IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.108.80.170
Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.254.0 
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 10.108.80.1

Comment: Sorry, my mistake: this is the diagnostics handler which usually listens on 224.0.75.75:7500. So check for port 7500. Note that you can disable it with `enable_diagnostics="false"`...

Comment: @BelaBan Awesome! Setting `enable_diagnostic="false"` fixed it. Are there any other ports we need to be aware of that need to be free?

Comment: Note that disabling diagnostics is not really a fix as you won't have monitoring capabilities any longer! I suggest adjusting `diagnostics_addr` / `diagnostics_port` instead...

Comment: Yes, I looked up the monitoring capabilities afterwards and changed the port.